# Gboard Chinese punctuation voice entry

Tags: input-methods

https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/2781851?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid says we can say "period", "comma" etc. That is for English.

But for Chinese, https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/2781851?hl=zh-Hant&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid just skirts the issue, with vague wording.

So I assume 逗點, 句點, 問號 are not recognized yet in the voice stream.

Comment: I have no problem using voice to input Chinese punctuation marks on my ios devices"我不知道，你知道嗎？ 人人都知道！ 知道就好了。The problem is when I want to write the words " 逗點, 句點, 問號" The voice input would give me "，。？" instead of the words

Comment: To get the words, I have to say 逗留的符號， 感嘆的符號，問題的符號，句子的符號 and cut the extra words out to make 逗號， 感嘆號，問號，句號. To say 開引號 and 關引號「」I have to say 打開引述符號 and 關閉引述符號 to get the words 開引號 and 關引號

Answer (score 0):

When using voice input in Chinese, punctuation is generally not directly pronounced , but is automatically detected based on tone(　ā　á　ǎ　à　). As for whether there are separate configuration functions on some software, it is unclear.

Comment: I'm talking about commas, periods and quotation marks etc I'm not talking about the first, second, third, or fourth tone symbols that are sitting on top of the pinyin letters. Nothing to do with pinyin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type a literal question mark or period in your text, you can say it just like in english "you want to go to the park question mark" becomes "you want to go to the park?"

however it will also try to auto detect punctuation, just like english, if you say nothing about it.  this is based on your over all phrases and pauses, to varying success.

As someone else mentioned, the most difficult thing is actually getting the literal word "question mark" typed, in chinese or english.  The computer really can't comprehend the context between a command to it and a word in the message, the ai isn't so advanced.

I don't think there is a solution for the third scenario in phone keyboards like gboard.  However I'll note that if you had a proper diction program on a computer they are heavily trainable and editable to match the individual voice and habits unique to the user, and you could definitely teach it two different commands, one each for the symbol "?" and the vocab "question mark"  etc.

Comment: If saying 逗點, 句點, 問號 actually created the corresponding punctuation, there would be no need for me to have posted my original question.